# Wimpy player - check if player playing

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I check if Wimpy player is playing?  I can see in the API that there is a `getStatus()` function but I'm not sure of the usage to determine if the player is playing:

http://www.wimpyplayer.com/docs/api/getStatus.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your supplied link
http://www.wimpyplayer.com/docs/api/getStatus.html

> **getStatus()**
>   The follow displays the data contained in the returned object
>
> **status**    Indicates if paused (0) or playing (1)

Sample

```
if (myPlayer.getStatus().status) {
    // playing
}
else {
    // not playing
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The latest version (v7.3.5) includes a new "getPlaying" API method. In addition, the returned object from getStatus includes a new "playing" field.

See:
http://www.wimpyplayer.com/docs/api/getPlaying.html

and: http://www.wimpyplayer.com/docs/api/getStatus.html